# Node.js Returning Null when Scraping HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm currently trying out some code which is meant to look for a specific torrent of Kickass Torrents as a proof of concept, but for some reason my simple code is failing to retun any value besides null, depsite the fact that I have confirmed that a torrent exists with the ID that I have in the program.

```
searchTerm = "photoshop"
var request = require("request"),
  cheerio = require("cheerio"),
  url = "https://kat.cr/usearch/" + searchTerm + "/";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body),
      magnet = $("[data-id='233B2C174D5FEF9D6AFAA61D150EC0B6F821D6A9'] href").html();
    console.log(magnet)
  } 
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a valid selector in the document it returns?

Comment: If you want to check out the source code from their website. View the source of https://kat.cr/usearch/photoshop/ and look around lines 210-215

Comment: @Jasch1 The text "data-id" does not exist in the URL you just posted.

Comment: http://imgur.com/dn1gwHF shows the part I am talking about. It is possible to use it as a selector

Comment: Try this: `$("#torrent_photoshop11014458 .iaconbox a.icon16")[1].attr('href');`

Comment: This gets a different response, but it still doesn't give the expected response. It now returns undefined instead of null

Comment: @Jasch1 I just updated, try again.

Comment: I get this error when I try to run it: 

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined

Comment: Oops my bad, I thought you were using jQuery, but the CSS selector `#torrent_photoshop11014458 .iaconbox a.icon16` should give you an array of 3 anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main KickAssTorrents site, kat.cr, encrypts the data that is returned. Instead, you could use http://kickasstorrentseu.com, which doesn't encrypt what is returned